# Why doesn't Unity 3D work?

Tags: unity, 3d

I have a small problem.
I have an Asus with a Nvidia GT630m k55vm and I want to install Ubuntu from a USB.

I select try without installing, and it works perfectly with the effects of Unity 3D mode, but when I install and run Ubuntu on the system, it doesn't work in 3D mode.

It starts up in 2D mode and the effects do not appear. What could I have done wrong?

---

Thanks for the answer. There is no driver available. But I don't understand why if it works well on the live cd, it doesn't work when ubuntu is completly installed.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you install your video drivers

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the proprietary Nvidia drivers?

In theory, shortly after installation, Ubuntu should notify you that "restricted drivers are available".

Otherwise, go to `System settings` -> `Additional drivers`. It should show you Nvidia drivers available for download. Select it, agree to the terms if necessary, install them and restart.

- [How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers)

Ubuntu is not allowed to distribute these drivers; therefore, they have to be installed explicitly by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Since, as you write, the drivers are not available from the Ubuntu repository (yet), you could install the drivers directly from the Nvidia [web site](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/object/linux-display-ia32-295.59-driver-uk.html). Apparently, it explicitly supports GT 630M.

I have no idea why it works in the live system. Of course, you can find out what driver and in which version is used by the X. You will find this information in the Xorg log files in `/var/log`. For example, one of my systems shows the following information:

```
(II) LoadModule: "intel"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
(II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.7.6, module version = 2.9.1
        Module class: X.Org Video Driver
        ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 6.0
(II) intel: Driver for Intel Integrated Graphics Chipsets: i810,
        i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 852GM/855GM, 865G, 915G,
        E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM, Pineview G,
        965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33, GM45,
        4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43, Clarkdale, Arrandale
```

The Xorg drivers are in packages with names like xserver-xorg-video-name, so one can find names and versions of the installed drivers as follows:

```
dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video
```

That way you can compare the system from the Live CD with the installed system.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the drivers on the Live CD and on the installed system and they are the same drivers, this is the result

> ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video ii 
>   xserver-xorg-video-all                 1:7.6+12ubuntu1
>   X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati
>   1:6.14.99~git20111219.aacbd629-0ubuntu2 X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI
>   display driver wrapper ii  xserver-xorg-video-cirrus
>   1:1.3.2-4build1                         X.Org X server -- Cirrus
>   display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
>   1:0.4.2-4ubuntu2                        X.Org X server -- fbdev
>   display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel
>   2:2.17.0-1ubuntu4                       X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx,
>   i9xx display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-mach64
>   6.9.0-1build2                           X.Org X server -- ATI Mach64 display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-mga
>   1:1.4.13.dfsg-4build2                   X.Org X server -- MGA display
>   driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-neomagic            1:1.2.5-2build2
>   X.Org X server -- Neomagic display driver ii 
>   xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
>   1:0.0.16+git20111201+b5534a1-1build2    X.Org X server -- Nouveau
>   display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
>   1:0.2.904+svn1050-1                     X.Org X server -- VIA display
>   driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-qxl                 0.0.16-2
>   X.Org X server -- QXL display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-r128
>   6.8.1-5build2                           X.Org X server -- ATI r128 display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon
>   1:6.14.99~git20111219.aacbd629-0ubuntu2 X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI
>   Radeon display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-s3
>   1:0.6.3-4build2                         X.Org X server -- legacy S3
>   display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-savage
>   1:2.3.3-1ubuntu1                        X.Org X server -- Savage
>   display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion
>   1:1.7.5-1build2                         X.Org X server --
>   SiliconMotion display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-sis
>   1:0.10.3-3build2                        X.Org X server -- SiS display
>   driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb              1:0.9.4-2build2
>   X.Org X server -- SiS USB display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-tdfx
>   1:1.4.3-4build2                         X.Org X server -- tdfx display
>   driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-trident             1:1.3.4-2build2
>   X.Org X server -- Trident display driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa
>   1:2.3.0-7build2                         X.Org X server -- VESA display
>   driver ii  xserver-xorg-video-vmware              1:12.0.1-1ubuntu1
>   X.Org X server -- VMware display driver

Do I try to install the drivers from the nvidia website?

Thanks